# What is the benefit of wordpress shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the picture below, two category news are show in home page and latest three news are show are in home page and other new are show category page. My question is that what is the best way to show this problem?

[image: picture]

Comment: your question is not clear, please elaborate it well.

Comment: ¿What is the problem?

Comment: my problem is that , i can not show two category post in my home page .